# Which type hint expresses that an attribute must not be None?

Tags: python, type-hinting, pydantic

In the following code, I need to declare `my_attr` as anything **except** `None`.

What should I exchange `Any` for?

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Any

class MyClass(BaseModel):
    my_attr: Any
```

Comment: @Georgy Thx for the hint. It's close to my case but does not reflect it completely, as in my case `pydantic` is in place and could offer other means to exclude `None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you would need to use a validator, something like:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class MyClass(BaseModel):
    my_attr: Any

    @validator('my_attr', always=True)
    def check_not_none(cls, value):
        assert value is not None, 'may not be None'
        return value
```

But it's unlikely this is actually what you want, you'd do better to use a union and include an exhaustive list of types you would allow, e.g. `Union[str, bytes, int, float, Decimal, datetime, date, list, dict, ...]`.

If you just want to make the field required (but with `None` still an allowed value), it should be possible after v1.2 which should be released in the next few days. see [samuelcolvin/pydantic#1031](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/pull/1031).