# Python type hint for anything but None?

Tags: python, types

Is there a type hint in the `typing` module indicating that something can be of any type *but* `None`/`NoneType`?

Like in this *hypothetical* example:

```py
def foo(bar: AnythingBut[None]):  # does this exist?
    if bar is None:
        raise Exception("bad!")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which type hint expresses that an attribute must not be None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59073717/which-type-hint-expresses-that-an-attribute-must-not-be-none)

Comment: @RandomDavis it _kinda_ does: including `pydantic.validator` was not an option (but could be made one), as my question referenced the `typing` module explicitly. but i get the idea it can't be done just with builtins, unless i'm willing to hardcode everything into `Union[...]`.

Comment: Altho this comes pretty close to the linked question, I think the `None` case deserves its own question because it gives too much grief when linter/checker is in strict mode... Also, have been googling something similar for a while now and this question appeared only in SO when I was about to post a dup!

Comment: Also, without being 100% sure, it seems you could used `bar: object` here but might have unwanted [side-effects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#the-any-type)

Comment: @RandomDavis That question asks for a solution using the pydantic library (and the answer provides one), while this answer asks for one in Python's built-in typing library.

Comment: On the other hand, the linked question ([Exclude type in Python typing annotation - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854871/exclude-type-in-python-typing-annotation)) from that question is pretty good.  ( tl;dr: there isn't. Just specify it in a docstring or meaningfully-named custom typevar.

Comment: There is no way to express "anything other than T", that doesn't really make sense as a type annotation